# Append dataframes to existing excel file's new sheets in R

Tags: r

I have a excel file `data.xlsx`, which has two sheets `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, now I want to append `df1` and `df2` from `R` into `data.xlsx` with names `Sheet3` and `Sheet4`, I have tried with:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(df1, "data.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet3", row.names = FALSE)
write.xlsx(df2, "data.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet4", row.names = FALSE)
```

But it overwrites the orginal file's `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, how could we solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643888/how-do-i-append-data-from-a-data-frame-in-r-to-an-excel-sheet-that-already-exist

Comment: In both occasions - your question and your answer - you didn't provide the name of the package you're using (I suppose it is `openxlsx`). In this way, you are the only person benefited with your question, which is not the intent of stackoverflow. You should edit question and answer to explicitly in a way that both encompass the package information.

Comment: I think it should be `library(xlsx)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may works:

```
library(xlsx)
# Write the first dataset df1 in a workbook
write.xlsx(df1, file = 'data.xlsx', sheetName = 'Sheet3, append = TRUE)
# Add a second dataset df2 in a new worksheet
write.xlsx(df2, file = 'data.xlsx', sheetName = 'Sheet4', append = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

The package xlsx allows you to do this.

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r#add-a-table-into-a-worksheet

Comment: Please don't add link only answers. Perhaps this is more suitable as a comment.

Comment: I wasn't able to add a comment to the original post - it said that I require some number of points to be able to post a comment.